# Slack - Add Custom Channel Group

Tags: slack

I've joined an organization that uses Slack. As such, there are a lot of pre-existing channels. I'm currently learning how to use it properly. I would like to add a customization to a channel, but I don't see how.

When I visit a channel's details, I see the following groups:

- About
- Members
- Organizations
- Shortcuts
- Pinned
- Files

I would like to add a new group that will allow me to post a block of HTML (or markdown if possible). My question is, is there a way to add a new/custom group? I haven't found a way. Yet, this seems like it would be a natural extension of a Slack channel. Am I missing something? If so, what?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the below answer provided useful to solve your problem? Or still, could not solve it?

Comment: @Pawara that does not solve the problem. Thank you though.

Comment: I appreciate it if you could explain your requirement in detail. I mean what features you want to customize?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new customized channel is easy. Follow the steps.

1. First navigate to your existing slack work-place and then **hover
   the mouse pointer** on channels dropdown. But do not click it. When
   you hover you will see an 'Add' button.
   [image: navigate to slack]
2. Then click the button and the following dropdown will appear. Click
   on
   '**Create channel**'
   [image: click on create new channel]
3. Then fill in the entries as I have done in the following demonstration. You can keep the channel either private or public. If it kept private others can't access it. You can later change the settings also.
   [image: fill the required entries to create the channel]
4. If you make the channel private you can add people to it. but for now, you can skip the option, too, and add whoever you would like to add later.
   [image: add people to the channel]
5. Now your channel is created and you can keep notes, upload notes, links and files, and can add any people you like from the work-place or outside.
   [image: start working on your new channel]

**I am sure this demonstration will help you to solve your issue.**